# Apply Drupal 8 Patch by Composer for fix multi fields on Signature Field

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-8, patch, drupal-modules

I try to patch the **Signature Field Drupal module**.

I follow this tutorial (https://groups.drupal.org/node/518975) but I don't get any changes.

What I try:

1-Run: `composer require cweagans/composer-patches`

2-Edit the `composer.json`

```
"extra": {
    "installer-paths": {
    ...
    },
    "patches": {
        "drupal/signature_field": { //here my module is signature_field
            "Drupal Signature Field fix multi feilds": "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/2019-02-21/signature_field-2993223-08.patch"     
        }
    }
}
```

3- Run `composer install`

**PROBLEM:** I run the `composer install` but all packages installed or updated but no change on my module. what is wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I search and try some way I got that I should install the module with the composer again and the issue will fix.

> Configuration in the question is fine
>   Just run this command to reinstall the module with patch

**Run** `composer require drupal/signature_field`

Your output will be like this:

[image]

I hope this help Some one!